# It's surprising that she would leave so suddenly. (would)

Tags: will-would

> When you consider how long she worked there, it's surprising that she would leave so suddenly.

'would'

The 'would' here implies she submitted her resignation?
In addition, 'so suddenly' gives me the feeling of her having done something suddenly.

What's the meaning of 'would'?

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence, the word **"would"** does not imply that she submitted her resignation. Instead, "would" is used to express surprise about her leaving based on the length of time she worked there.

The phrase **"so suddenly"** refers to the suddenness or unexpected nature of her departure. It does not imply that she did something suddenly, but rather emphasizes the surprise at her leaving without prior indication or warning.

Comment: What do you think is the meaning of 'would' here?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, **"would"** is used to express surprise about her leaving based on the length of time she worked there.

Comment: Does it mean she has already left? or is she still thinking of it

Comment: @YvesLefol It means that she has already left.

Comment: @ITTSUTFSA There are a lot of usages of 'would' in a dictionary and wonder why you are sure of her having left.

Comment: the fact the author used "would" does it mean that at the time of writing he was not sure that she had already  left , if he was sure he would have written "left " not "would leave"